# Google Addon/Drive "Open With..." Support

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a Google Addon such that when a user is in Drive, it will first request the right scopes to get access to the user's GDrive and then create a shortcut file to my app (which lives on an external site). The flow in this [Drive UI Integration](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-apps) article ("Open with...") is roughly what I'm trying to implement.

This is mostly working and I'm able to create the shortcut file in a folder of my choosing like so (after enabling the Advanced Drive API in my Addon of course):

```
const file = Drive.Files.insert({title: name, mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk'});
  Drive.Parents.insert(folder, file.id);
```

Then, when I right-click this file and choose "Open with...", I'm able to see an option to open this file but when I click this, I get the nebulous error:

> Sorry, we were unable to authorize this app for all of the files you attempted to open. Please try again.

I'm guessing the issue is that I don't have a "Drive UI Integration" setup to handle the "Open with..." option for this file. If that's true, it's not clear to me how I would set this up. I don't see an app/OAuth credential in my GCP console that corresponds to the Google Addon such that I could enable the Drive UI Integration.

Is there a way to setup a "Drive UI Integration" to enable "Open with..." support in a Google Addon?

Comment: which scope did you request access for?

Comment: "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.addons.metadata.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]